# How to achieve the results into a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below

```
;with cte as(
Select  1 as Col1 ,NULL as Col2
Union All

Select Null ,2)

select *
from cte
```

/* Result*/

```
Col1         Col2
1            NULL
NULL          2
```

I am looking for

```
Col1         Col2
1             2
```

i.e.  results should come in a single row.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more details about your data, it seems like applying a simple aggregate function like `max` should do what you are after:

```
...
select max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2
  from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(col1) , MAX(col2) FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any aggregate function like Max() or Min() or Sum() depends on your requirement
.

Answer (score 1):

1With the limited information in your question is this what your trying achieve?

```
;with cte as(
Select  table1.Col1 , table2.Col2 From Table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.col1 = table2.Col1
WHERE table1.Col1 = 1 and table2.Col2 = 2
)

select *
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Using cartesian join we can get the required result:

```
select t2.a,t1.b from table t1,table t2 where t1.b is not null and t2.a is not null;
```